# Stripe Elements React implementation with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to type my `PaymentForm` class component for using `react-stripe-js` as per documented [here](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js#using-class-components).

The component works as expected, however I haven't found any example with TS and mainly for the `elements` from the `StripeProps` interface. I'm using `any` which is of course not desirable.

I already figured out `stripe` which uses `Stripe` from `'@stripe/stripe-js'`.

Unfortunately, using functional component is not an option. So class component must be used here.

```
import { loadStripe, Stripe, StripeElements } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements, ElementsConsumer, CardElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

export interface Props {
    loading: boolean;
    buttonName: string;
    showCancel?: boolean;
    error?: Error;
    onSubmit(token: string): void;
    onCancel?(): void;
}

interface StripeProps {
  stripe: Stripe;
  // to do: add types for elements
  elements: any;
  // tried with StripeElements from @stripe/stripe-js
}

class PaymentForm extends React.PureComponent<
  Props & StripeProps, State
> {
  ...

  handleSubmit = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    const { stripe, elements } = this.props;

    if (elements === null) {
      return;
    }

    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);

    ...

    stripe.createToken(cardElement, { name: this.state.name })
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ loading: false });

        if (data.token) {
          this.props.onSubmit(data.token.id);
        }

        if (data.error) {
          this.setState({ error:
            (data.error as stripe.Error).message || 'An unknown error occurred.',
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }

  ...

  render() {
    ...

    return (
      <form className="payment-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        ...
        <div className="card">
          <div className="description">
            Card
          </div>
          <CardElement
            className="card-element"
            style={{
              base: {
                color: '#444444',
                fontSize: '14px',
                fontFamily: DEFAULT_FONT,
                fontWeight: '400',
                '::placeholder': {
                  color: '#c9d4e0',
                },
              } as any,
            }}
          />
        </div>
        ...
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const InjectedCheckoutForm = (props: Props) => (
  <ElementsConsumer>
    {({ elements, stripe }: StripeProps) => (
      <PaymentForm
        {...props}
        elements={elements}
        stripe={stripe}
      />
    )}
  </ElementsConsumer>
);

const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY as string);

const WrappedPaymentForm: React.SFC<Props> = (props: Props) => (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <InjectedCheckoutForm {...props} />
  </Elements>
);

 export default WrappedPaymentForm;
```

I was checking the `StripeElements` interface ([github file](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js/blob/master/src/types/index.ts)) and it should work.

Anyone out there who has made this implementation with TS?

Comment: Having trouble understanding what the actual ask is. Are you seeing an error? Are you not seeing something work as expected?

Comment: I don't want to use `any` in for `elements` in the `StripeProps` interface